# jQuery Datatable Checkbox function issue

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Here is my Fiddle link, i tried to create checkbox on the first column, for that i customized the php code and created the checkboxes, but i coludnt function the checkall fields and stop the processing when i click the header checkbox.

Help me to solve, may be its an available question, but my php code is little different and even the problem also not similar to the existing one.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/
```

and here is my tried page.
[kvcodes](http://cdn.kvcodes.com/datatablephp/try2.html)

Comment: Not answer, clickable link http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/

Comment: (1) you never call your `function OnSelectAllCheckBoxClicked(cb)`, (2) you don't have any checkboxes with `[name^="rowselect"]`

Comment: `$('.group-checkable').on('click',function(){ OnSelectAllCheckBoxClicked(this) });` && `function OnSelectAllCheckBoxClicked(cb) { $('input[type=checkbox]').not(cb).prop('checked', cb.checked); }`? jsFiddle updated -http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/1/

Comment: Thank you so munch Sean,  I have one more problem.  Here if i enable serverside processing, the search field gives me a trouble. Actually i need to filter it individually,  but go here,   [kvcodes_try](http://cdn.kvcodes.com/datatablephp/try2.html) here , just try filter office by entering "ghost" on the office search field.  it results  zero.  but if you try type the "ghost " on position"  it filters.  i mean the column filter changed its locations. one column before the search field.    Please help me on this.  if you dont understand try  the demo else comment me please.  dont vote it down.